# Problema al inicializar un vector dentro de una clase

Tags: c++

Buenas, 
Tengo un problema a la hora de iniciar un vector. Éste se inicia cuando llamo a la función Especie de la clase. En principio se crea bien, pero cuando lo intento usar, me dice que tiene tamaño 0.

Esta es la clase:

```
#include "Especie.hh"

Especie::Especie() {
    cin >> N;
    cin >> l0;
    int m = N + 2;
    vector<int> ln (m);
    for(int i = 2; i < m; ++i) cin >> ln[i];
    cin >> ln[0] >> ln[1];
    cout << ln.size() << endl; //Aquí vemos que el tamaño es el correcto (7 con la entrada concreta que he puesto)
}

int Especie::n_normals() {
    return N;
}


int Especie::tall_sexuals() {
    return l0;
}


int Especie::mida(int i) {
    return ln[i];
}

int Especie::mida2() {
    return ln.size();
}
```

Y este el codigo de testeo:

```
#include "Especie.hh"

int main() {
    Especie e;
    cout << e.mida2() << endl;  //Aquí ya se ve que tiene longitud 0
    int n = e.n_normals();
    cout << n << endl;
    int ts = e.tall_sexuals();
    cout << ts << endl;

    int m;
    for(int i = 0; i < n+2; ++i) {
        m = e.mida(i);
        cout << m;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Aquí una entrada de prueba:
5 
3 6 7 6 7 6
5 3

Pongo también el hh:

```
#ifndef ESPECIE_HH
#define ESPECIE_HH

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Especie {

private:
    int N; //num. cromosomas normales
    int l0; //punto de corte
    vector<int> ln; //vector con la long. de los cromosomas

public:

    Especie(); //lee los datos de la especie en el canal de entrada

    int n_normals(); //Devuelve el num. de cromosomas normales N

    int tall_sexuals(); //Devuelve el punto de corte en los crom. sexuales

    int mida(int i); //Devuelve ln[i](long. del crom. i)

    int mida2(); //Devuelve el tamaño de ln
};
#endif
```

Hay cosas en catalán pero supongo que no es un gran problema.

Espero que puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bona tarda! ;)
###Problema.
Tienes un problema al mezclar variables locales con variables miembro, en concreto en el constructor de la clase, te lo marco con comentarios:

```
Especie::Especie() {
    cin >> N;
    cin >> l0;
    int m = N + 2;

    /* Este 'ln' es local a la funcion 'Especie::Especie',
       no hace referencia a la variable miembro 'Especie::ln' */
    vector<int> ln (m);
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-------- VARIABLE LOCAL A Especie::Especie.

    for(int i = 2; i < m; ++i) cin >> ln[i];
    cin >> ln[0] >> ln[1];
    cout << ln.size() << endl;
}
```

###Solución.
No debes construir una variable nueva, usa la ya existente (tal y como ya haces con `N` y `l0`), te lo marco con comentarios:

```
Especie::Especie() {
    cin >> N;
    cin >> l0;
    int m = N + 2;

    ln.resize(m);
  //~~ <-------- VARIABLE MIEMBRO Especie::ln.

    for(int i = 2; i < m; ++i) cin >> ln[i];
    cin >> ln[0] >> ln[1];
    cout << ln.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Vaaale, ahora lo entiendo. Gracias! Al final lo había resuleto poniendo un vector auxiliar y al final haciendo "ln = aux;" Pero así queda mejor, y me molestaba no entender por qué no funcionaba, así que gracias :)